# How can correctly save a csv with values list from neooffice / openoffice?

Tags: csv

I need something like this:

```
Attivato;Nome;Categorie;Prezzo tasse escluse;Descrizione;Immagini
1;"Bracciale rock";11,12,13;130;"This is a long description.";http://s20.postimg.org/r08w8i4i5/perle.jpg,http://s20.postimg.org/tmjtbp6bx/bracciale.jpg
```

But if I open it with neooffice calc (or anyway in some spreadsheet program) it then export like this, at the best:

```
Attivato;Nome;Categorie;Prezzo tasse escluse;Descrizione;Immagini
1;"Bracciale rock";"11,12,13";130;"This is a long description.";"http://s20.postimg.org/r08w8i4i5/perle.jpg,http://s20.postimg.org/tmjtbp6bx/bracciale.jpg"
```

It won't retain things like 11,12,13 without converting them to strings

How can I fix this?

I tried really everything but no way... Tried any kind of import/export options, different programs, etc... I cannot do it.

Comment: in which way is this programming, software-development related?

Comment: `converting them to strings` ???? They **are** strings, either with or without the quotes.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a space after your numbers just before the `commata`, so it is not parsed as one large string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a couple of ways.

(1) In neooffice/openoffice:

- left empty the text separator field
- check the 'detect special numbers' option

[image: neooffice open file palette]

(2) As another alternative, I used google docs. That's good also to use for clients who usually use exel. Google docs/drive saves csv files in utf-8 encoding by default. 
Also, for the problem of "string conversion" of multiple values like 5,7,9,6, I found that if you use semicolons (;) instead of commas, that works (I mean, it doesn't add "" when you save as csv AND doesn't read them as dates or other wrong data types). And in prestashop you can set the field and test separators accordingly.

Hope it helps other people.